# Source for difference between the tenth (final) shira and all previous shiros

Tags: midrash, shiras-hayam

I heard once that the tenth shir that will be sung upon the coming of Mashiach will be different than all the previous shiros. The other nine all mention the downfall of our enemies, but this shir will not. I am desperately looking for the source of this idea, if anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The idea that there are 10 shiros and that the 10th will differ from the last in that it represents the final redemption is stated clearly in the Mechilta D'Rebbi Yishmael and Mechilta D'Rebbi Shimon ben Yochai on the verse of "Az Yashir" (Shemos, 15;1):

> ״אֶת הַשִּׁירָה הַזֹּאת״. וְכִי שִׁירָה אַחַת הִיא? וַהֲלֹא עֶשֶׂר
> שִׁירוֹת הֵן: **הָרִאשׁוֹנָה**, שֶׁנֶּאֶמְרָה בְמִצְרַיִם,
> שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (ישעיה ל,כט) "הַשִּׁיר יִהְיֶה לָכֶם כְּלֵיל הִתְקַדֶּשׁ
> חָג". **הַשְּׁנִיָּה**, שֶׁנֶּאֶמְרָה עַל הַיָּם, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (שמות
> טו,א) "אָז יָשִׁיר מֹשֶׁה". **השְׁלִישִׁית**, שֶׁנֶּאֶמְרָה עַל
> הַבְּאֵר, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (במדבר כא,יז) "אָז יָשִׁיר יִשְׂרָאֵל".
> **הָרְבִיעִית** שֶׁאָמַר מֹשֶׁה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (על פי דְּבָרִים לא,כד) 'וַיְהִי כְּכַלּוֹת מֹשֶׁה לִכְתֹּב אֶת דִּבְרֵי הַשִּׁירָה הַזֹּאת'.
> **הַחֲמִישִׁית** שֶׁאָמַר יְהוֹשֻׁעַ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (יהושע י,יב) "אָז יְדַבֵּר יְהוֹשֻׁעַ לַיי, בְּיוֹם תֵּת יי אֶת הָאֱמֹרִי לִפְנֵי בְּנֵי
> יִשְׂרָאֵל, וַיֹּאמֶר לְעֵינֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל: שֶׁמֶשׁ בְּגִבְעוֹן דּוֹם,
> וְיָרֵחַ בְּעֵמֶק אַיָּלוֹן." **הַשִּׁשִּׁית**, שֶׁאָמְרָה דְבוֹרָה
> וּבָרָק, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (שופטים ה,א) "וַתָּשַׁר דְּבוֹרָה וּבָרָק בֶּן
> אֲבִינֹעַם". **הַשְּׁבִיעִית** שֶׁאָמַר דָּוִד, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (שמואל ב
> כב,א) ״וַיְדַבֵּר דָּוִד לַיי אֶת דִּבְרֵי הַשִּׁירָה הַזֹּאת״.
> **הַשְּׁמִינִית** שֶׁאָמַר שְׁלֹמֹה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (תהלים ל,א) ״מִזְמוֹר שִׁיר חֲנֻכַּת הַבַּיִת לְדָוִד״. **הַתְּשִׁיעִית**,
> שֶׁאָמַר יְהוֹשָׁפָט, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (דברי הימים ב כ,כא) "וַיִּוָּעַץ
> אֶל הָעָם, וַיַּעֲמֵד מְשֹׁרְרִים לַיי, וּמְהַלְלִים לְהַדְרַת קֹדֶשׁ,
> בְּצֵאת לִפְנֵי הֶחָלוּץ, וְאֹמְרִים: הוֹדוּ לַיי, כִּי לְעוֹלָם
> חַסְדּוֹ!" וּמָה נִשְׁתַּנֵּית הוֹדָיָה זוֹ מִכָּל הוֹדָיוֹת
> שֶׁבַּתּוֹרָה? שֶׁבְּכָל הוֹדָיוֹת שֶׁבַּתּוֹרָה נֶאֱמַר: "הוֹדוּ לַיי
> כִּי טוֹב, כִּי לְעוֹלָם חַסְדּוֹ!" וּבָזוֹ לֹא נֶאֱמַר "כִּי טוֹב".
> אֶלָּא כִּבְיָכֹל **לֹא הָיְתָה שִׂמְחָה לְפָנָיו בַּמָּרוֹם. עַל
> מִיתָתָן שֶׁלָּרְשָׁעִים, לֹא הָיְתָה שִׂמְחָה לְפָנָיו**, קַל וָחֹמֶר
> עַל אֲבֵדָתוֹ שֶׁלְּצַדִּיק אֶחָד, שֶׁהוּא שָׁקוּל כְּנֶגֶד הָעוֹלָם
> כֻּלּוֹ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (משלי י,כה) ״וְצַדִּיק יְסוֹד עוֹלָם״.
> **הָעֲשִׂירִית** לֶעָתִיד לָבֹא, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (ישעיה מב,י) "שִׁירוּ לַיי שִׁיר חָדָשׁ, תְּהִלָּתוֹ מִקְצֵה הָאָרֶץ", וְאוֹמֵר: (תהלים
> קמט,א) "שִׁירוּ לַיי שִׁיר חָדָשׁ, תְּהִלָּתוֹ בִּקְהַל חֲסִידִים."
> כָּל הַשִּׁירוֹת שֶׁעָבְרוּ קְרוּיוֹת בִּלְשׁוֹן נְקֵבָה. כַּשֵּׁם
> שֶׁהַנְּקֵבָה יוֹלֶדֶת, כָּךְ הַתְּשׁוּעוֹת שֶׁעָבְרוּ, הָיָה
> אַחֲרֵיהֶם שִׁעְבּוּד, אֲבָל הַתְּשׁוּעָה הָעֲתִידָה קְרוּיָה
> בִּלְשׁוֹן זָכָר, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (ירמיה ל,ו) "שַׁאֲלוּ נָא וּרְאוּ, אִם
> יֹלֵד זָכָר, מַדּוּעַ רָאִיתִי כָל גֶּבֶר יָדָיו עַל חֲלָצָיו?"
> כַּשֵּׁם שֶׁאֵין הַזָּכָר יוֹלֵד, כָּךְ הַתְּשׁוּעָה הָעֲתִידָה לָבֹא,
> אֵין אַחֲרֶיהָ שִׁעְבּוּד, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: (ישעיה מה,יז) ״יִשְׂרָאֵל
> נוֹשַׁע בַּיי תְּשׁוּעַת עוֹלָמִים, לֹא תֵבֹשׁוּ וְלֹא תִכָּלְמוּ עַד
> עוֹלְמֵי עַד.״
>
> "This song": Is there only one song? Behold there are ten "songs."
> **The first**, that sung in Egypt, viz. (Isaiah 30:29) "The song (of Sancherev's destruction [on Pesach night]) will be to you as that of
> the night on which you sanctified the festival (Pesach [in Egypt]),
> etc." **The second**, that of the sea — "Then Moses sang." **The
> third**, that of the well (Numbers 21:17) "Then Israel sang." **The
> fourth**, that of Moses, viz. (Devarim 31:22) "And Moses wrote this
> song (32:1-43). **The fifth**, that of Joshua, viz. (Joshua 10:12)
> "Then Joshua spoke to the L–rd on the day the L–rd delivered, etc."
> **The sixth**, that of Devorah and Barak, viz. (Judges 5:1) "And Devorah and Barak the son of Avinoam sang, etc." **The seventh**, that
> of David, viz. (II Samuel 22:1) "And David spoke to the L–rd the words
> of this song, etc". **The eighth**, that of Solomon, viz. (Psalms
> 30:1) "A psalm, a song of the inauguration of the Temple of David"...
> **The ninth** (song): (II Chronicles 20:21) "And he (Yehoshafat) took counsel with the people, and he set up singes to the L–rd and lauders
> of (His) majestic holiness. When they went out before the vanguard (of
> the army) they said; 'Give thanks to the L–rd, for His lovingkindness
> is forever!'" Why is this thanksgiving different from all the other
> sin the Torah, where it is written "Give thanks to the L–rd for (the
> good, for His lovingkindness is forever"? — It is to say, as it were,
> **that there is no rejoicing before Him over the destruction of the wicked**. If over that of the wicked there is no rejoicing, how much
> more so (is there grief) over that of the righteous, one of whom is
> over and against the entire world, viz. (Mishlei 10:25) "And the
> righteous one is the foundation of the world". **The tenth** (song) in
> time to come, viz. (Isaiah 42;10) "Sing to the L–rd a new song, His
> praise from the end of the earth (Ibid. 48:42) "Say: The L–rd has
> redeemed His servant Jacob. All of the (other) songs are denominated
> in the feminine ("zoth"). Just as a female bears (and then travails
> again), so, the past salivations were followed by subjugation. But the
> future (ultimate) redemption will not be followed by subjugation —
> wherefore it is denominated in the masculine ("zeh" [viz. Isaiah
> 26:1]). As it is written (Jeremiah 30:6) "Ask now and see if a male
> has ever given birth. Why, then, do I see that every man puts his
> hands upon his loins (as a woman giving birth?") For just as a male
> does not bear (and thus travail), so, the future redemption will not
> be followed by subjugation. As it is written (Isaiah 45:17) "Israel
> will be saved by the L–rd, an eternal salvation. You will not be
> ashamed or abashed forever."

There idea that the previous nine speak of the destruction of our enemies and the tenth won't, doesn't seem to be true from this Midrash, in fact (as I highlighted) the Midrash emphasizes the fact that the *ninth* shirah differs in that Hashem is pained by the destruction of the wicked.